# Call elasticsearch with PreBuiltTransportClient

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I create a new running docker elastic instance:

```
docker run --name i3-ps-elastic -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.3
```

It responds well to http calls:

```
$ curl localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "_wqolsQ",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "m2Mh9oXaSbiPF2UQprrB-Q",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.3",
    "build_hash" : "eed30a8",
    "build_date" : "2017-06-22T00:34:03.743Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Notice how cluster_name is set to the same value in client and server.

But then I run the following test:

```
@Test
public void checkElasticConnection() throws UnknownHostException {

    Settings.Builder settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "docker-cluster");
    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings.build());
    client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

    assertThat(client).isNotNull();
    ClusterHealthResponse clusterHealthResponse = client.admin().cluster().prepareHealth().get();
    assertThat(clusterHealthResponse).isNotNull();
}
```

And I get:

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{hRbm7zJ1TR6p_KdmohkCFQ}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:347)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:245)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:378)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:405)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:394)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$ClusterAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:706)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:53)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue for me was that I had a version mismatch between server and client. My server was `5.4.3` and client `6.3.0`. I solved this by removing the docker instance and running the matching version instead:

```
docker run --name i3-ps-elastic -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.0
```